# Create an array of objects for items greater than zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create an array of objects for items greater than zero. I have the following code:

```
const payments = [];
if (values.ops > 0) {
  payments.push({
    "tax": options.find(item => item.value === "ops"),
    "type": ops.find(item => item.value === "tax"),
    "year": values.year,
    "period": ops.find(item => item.type === "period"),
    "sum": values.ops
  })
};
if (values.ops1 > 0) {
  payments.push({
    "tax": options.find(item => item.value === "ops1"),
    "type": ops1.find(item => item.value === "tax"),
    "year": values.year,
    "period": ops1.find(item => item.type === "period"),
    "sum": values.ops1
  })
};
if (values.oms > 0) {
  payments.push({
    "tax": options.find(item => item.value === "oms"),
    "type": oms.find(item => item.value === "tax"),
    "year": values.year,
    "period": oms.find(item => item.type === "period"),
    "sum": values.oms
  })
};
```

Is there any way to simplify this, so that I could check if an item is greater than 0 and make `payments.push` only once?

Comment: Could you please post an example for `values` variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `mapper` object using [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). This will map `"ops"` key with `ops` array as value and so on. Then loop through the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of this object and push to the `payments`  array based on `values[key]`

```js
const mapper = {
  ops,
  ops1,
  oms
}

const payments = []

for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(mapper)) {
  if (values[key] > 0)
    payments.push({
      "tax": options.find(item => item.value === key),
      "type": array.find(item => item.value === "tax"),
      "year": values.year,
      "period": array.find(item => item.type === "period"),
      "sum": values[key]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const payments = [];

[
  "ops", 
  "ops1", 
  "oms"
].forEach(prop=>{
    if(values[props]>0){
        payments;.push({
            tax: options.find(item => item.value === prop),
            type: ops.find(item => item.value === "tax"),
            year: values.year,
            period: ops.find(item => item.type === "period"),
            sum: values[prop]
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: for `type` and `period`, the `ops` array is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for `ops`, `ops1` and `oms` and iterate the keys and oush new objects if necessary.

```
data = { ops, ops1, oms }

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
    if (values[k] <= 0) return;
    payments.push({
        tax: options.find(item => item.value === k),
        type: data[k].find(item => item.value === "tax"),
        year: values.year,
        period: data[k].find(item => item.type === "period"),
        sum: values[k]
    });
});
```